# What is difference between bundle.getString() and intent.getStringExtra()?

Tags: android

What is the difference between `bundle.getString()` and `intent.getStringExtra()` ?

I am new to Android, still learning, just curious to know the differences between both.

Comment: The difference is that one is a method of `Bundle` and the other is a method of `Intent`. Can you be more specific about what exactly you want to know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With **`Intent.getStringExtra()`** we get the Bundled string data directly from the intent object.

To be precise, we can get the string data from intent with **`Bundle`** object like this:

```
// Call from received activity or component.
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String value1 = extras.getString("OUR_TEXT_KEY");
```

So, `Bundle.getString()` is the same as `Intent.getExtras.getString()`. Bundle object is within the Intent.

Please read about [`Intent.getExtras()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()).

Comment: hi @ישו אוהב אותך   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968587/android-email-client-receiver-email-id-empty-in-android-parse   hi please check this if you can

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that by using the Intent, you'll prevent a NullPointerException from `getIntent().getExtras()` possibly returning null when there is no extras to get. And `intent.getStringExtra()` will simply return null as the default value.

Otherwise, the Intent method is simply a shortcut to getting the Bundle, then getting the value from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Extra` or `Extras` by the following methods :

Method 1 :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userName", "Noor");
        bundle.putString("id", "123");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Admin.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Method 2 :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Admin.class);
    intent.putExtra("userName", "Noor");
    intent.putExtra("id", "123");
    startActivity(intent);
```

And get those `Extra` or `Extras` by the following Method :

Method 1:

```
String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");
        String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

Method 2:

```
Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();
        assert bundle1 != null;
        String userName1 = bundle1.getString("userName");
        String id1 = bundle1.getString("id");
```

You can use any of the above method simply. Also You can use above cross Method correspondingly. There is no difference to set and get the value.